# Visual Studio 2013 custom toolbar to insert code snippets

Tags: visual-studio-2013, code-snippets, visual-studio-extensions

Could anyone point me in the right direction here?  I am adding a custom toolbar and I want buttons for lots of different code snippets.  We use so many that it is impracticable to remember all the different shortcut commands for each one, and selecting from a menu takes longer than just clicking a button.

It doesn't really even need to be specifically for a code snippet as defined by Visual studio, just simply pasting some text to the editor window, however I was hoping to be able to have some that would work as surround snippets, which the normal code snippets do.

Comment: So, your question is basically: How to insert text in the active Code-Window with a VS extension?

Comment: Yeah I suppose that would be a better wording.  I am too much of a noob to even know the correct language sometimes :D

Answer (score 0):

You should call this:

`(DTE2)base.GetService(typeof(DTE))`

in the `Initialize()` method of the Package and save the resulting dte-instance in a field. When your button is clicked, you can use `((TextDocument)_DTE.ActiveDocument).Selection.Text)` to retrieve the currently selected text, modify it and write it back as new selected text. Maybe you will have to cast the return value of the `Selection`-Property to `TextSelection`.

Comment: Ahh excellent I was wondering how I was going to implement the surround functionality for the code snippets.  And to simply paste in some text stored maybe in some XML somewhere?  It seems like I would be able to call part of the code snippet functionality from a button rather than the built in method.  Then I could use the normal way of creating a snippet xml file for the snippets themselves.